# How to install Sass as a dependency with Composer?

Tags: sass, composer-php

I'm using Composer as a dependency manager for a WordPress project. I'm specifying plugins and WP-CLI as dependencies in composer.json like so:

```
"require": {
  "johnpbloch/wordpress": "5.8.*",
  "wp-cli/wp-cli-bundle": "*",
  "wpackagist-plugin/akismet": "*"
}
```

Here's the [documentation on installing WP CLI via Composer](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/guides/installing/#installing-via-composer). This works great. However, I would also like to include the latest version of [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/install) this way, so that new people on the project can get that installed via Composer without having to do it manually.

I cannot count on everyone having npm, Chocolatey, or Homebrew, and I won't know what operating system they use.

Alternately, how could I install the latest version of SASS cross-OS via [a script that Composer runs using post-install-cmd](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md)?

Comment: What makes you think that this is possible? As SASS is not written in PHP, you definitely need to install other parts that Composer cannot install for your, so there would be little help if SASS alone got installed using Composer

Comment: @nico-haase I know Composer is written in PHP, and it is primarily used for managing php dependencies, but if there is something about it being only possible to use for PHP dependencies, I am not seeing that explicitly on https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no package for Sass (and it makes sense there wouldn't be, unless sass could be installed as a stand-alone binary or something like that), you cannot install Sass as a composer dependency

Which in any case wouldn't make much sense, since Sass cannot be a dependency for a PHP project, as it has nothing to do with PHP.

> Alternately, how could I install the latest version of SASS cross-OS via a script that Composer runs using post-install-cmd?

The [install instructions for Sass](https://sass-lang.com/install) include no provisions for a "cross OS installer without using npm". So unles you write a script checking for the OS, what does it have installed, etc (which would be brittle and some **serious** overkill), you cannot automate this with a `post-install-cmd`.

Which again, wouldn't make a lot of sense in any case. If the package consumers need to use sass part of the project, it's a given they are developers and are capable of going through the sass requirements.

Point your package consumers to the appropriate documentation and be done.